# Google Calendar update/patch API giving 403 error

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a couple of resources added to my Gsuite and I am managing events of these resources from APIs.

**Authentication & Authorization**

- I have generated oAuth creds , API key from the developer console. Provided necessary Scopes.
- Resource Calendar emails are shared with my Calendar from settings & sharing option in Google Calendar.

`SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']`

**APIs**

- GET APIs are working fine but when I am trying to use update/patch APIs then it is giving me the error.
- I also tried using the API explorer since this here scopes/tokens are handled by Google itself so it should work fine, but NO I am getting the same 403 error in API explorer too.
- Interesting thing is if I pass the wrong body in Patchcall then it will give me 400 error but with the correct body it will give me 403.

Old SO questions Answer suggested to check Scopes, Share Resource Calendar in your Google Calendar, BUt I verified all these things and they are fine. I can verify the Granted scopes from token generated responses and even from the Account Settings Third APP page.

```
    curl --location --request PATCH 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_resource.calendar.google.com/events/<event_id>>' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "status": "cancelled"
}'
```

In above curl :

- Token is of my gsuite user account > let's say `user@custom_domain.com`
- calendarID is Gsuite Resource > `my_resource.calendar.google.com`
- eventUId is > created from user@custom_domain.com and select `my_resource.calendar.google.com` as Room.
- Thsi resource email `my_resource.calendar.google.com` is added in `user@custom_domain.com` Calendar. So user can manage events created on resource

But I am getting 403 error. Is there anything I am missing here in configuration ?

**UPDATE**

Error Message

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden",
                "message": "Forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Forbidden"
    }
}
```

Comment: When running the update/patch, are you running it as your service account or are you impersonating a Super Admin from your organization?

Comment: please post the full error message.

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz No, I am not using Service Account. I am using Tokens of a Normal User but that user has access to those Resources Calendar and required SCOPES are also permitted.

Comment: @DaImTo Upadted my Question with error message.

Comment: The forbidden error matches a sharing permissions missing from the normal user that is being used to access the resources. Have you changed the sharing permissions in your Admin console of your organization?  https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz Exactly what Sharing permission are we talking here since  Token user is an internal User of organisation, and `Internal sharing options` is applicable only on primary calendars` any document link to enable that particular sharing permission ?

Comment: The internal user being used as a token is a Super Admin of the organization? And the configuration can be found here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6262207

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz No, Token User is not a Super Admin.

Comment: Which would explain the issue when trying to update. As suggested by the documentation, resources are available to view by the organization, however editing permission might not be available due to the user not being a Super Admin that can perform any action on that Calendar or due to the configuration of the sharing permissions. It is worth testing the option to make the token user a Super Admin if possible, it should allow editing and would help with the patch or update that is basically requesting an edit permission.

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz Yes I agree with you. Super Admin Token will do the job. But if you have an application which in the end will ntegrate with client's Gsuite then in most cases you will not receive Super Admin Tokens (due to security concern). And conceptually if you have access to Calendar and Proper SCOPES then you must be able to update/patch events of that Calendar. Otherwise how we are supposed to manage Resources events using oAuth Tokens ?